# How to get all wxListbook items?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a `wxListbook` that has some items, the following it is just a preview picture:

[image]

I want to get all item titles but before that, I want to get all items first then creating a for loop which in turn getting each item's title.

I found a method called `GetListView()` but it doesn't return array-like.

**Is there a method to get all the items of that `wxListbook`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxListbook` inherits from [wxBookCtrlBase](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.1/classwx_book_ctrl_base.html) which defines `GetPageCount()` and `GetPageText()` methods that you can use to iterate over the pages and retrieve their labels, respectively.